# Ruby authorization based on profile and target object

Tags: ruby, rubygems, authorization

I'm working on a project that involves creating users with specific characteristics like:

- My Company
- My Business Line (within the company)
- My Department (within the Business Line)

The purpose of this application is to manage and follow up deals.

Each user can create deals, which are automatically linked to their company, their Business Line, and their Department.

All users that do not belong to the same Company, Business Line, and Department cannot access the deal. In other words, a user can only access the deals which share the same characteristics with the user.

Is it possible to build such a complicated authorization matrix with traditional ruby gems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make a query to find all the items the user can access. Assuming the user has only one company, department and business line:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :company
  has_one :department
  has_one :business_line

  def deals
     Deal.where(company_id: company_id, 
          business_line_id: business_line_id,
             department_id: department_id
  end
end
```